# Can Two MySQL Password Policies Policies Cause an Error to not Satisfy the Current Policy Requirements

Tags: mysql

I can not create users on MySQL because of an error "Your Password does not satisfy the Current Policy Requirements"

I have run the command:
`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';`

And I find there are two password policies.

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password.length             | 8      |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password.policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1      |
| validate_password_check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password_length             | 8      |
| validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password_policy             | LOW    |
| validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is a sample string that fails:

```
CREATE USER 'support_usr'@'gk1qYu!n%';
ALTER USER 'support_usr'@'gk1qYu!n%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'Pxuzj#1M4!d' ;
```

Could this be a conflict that prevents user password creation? Is there a way to remove one or both of them?

Comment: Can you show us a password you think satisfies the current policy requirements, but MySQL does not?

Comment: Updated as requested @Schwern

Comment: Figured it out. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing because the account is created with no password. The MySQL docs have an example.

> This account-creation statement fails, even though the account is locked initially, because it does not include a password that satisfies the current password policy:

> ```
> mysql> CREATE USER 'juanita'@'localhost' ACCOUNT LOCK;
> ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
> ```

You must create a user with their password.

```
create user 'support_usr'@'gk1qYu!n%' identified by 'Pxuzj#1M4!d' ;
```

---

You have variables for two different versions of MySQL. Prior to MySQL 8, [they were `validate_password_xxx`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/validate-password.html). MySQL 8 [changed this to `validate_password.xxx`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/validate-password.html). MySQL 8 has [instructions on how to transition from the old to the new](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/validate-password-transitioning.html).